# Using mutt commnd with strace -f fails

Tags: linux, bash, shell, strace, mutt

I'm using the [mutt](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/mutt.htm) command in linux and it works when running it regularly.

```
mutt myOwnMail@server.com -s "some_subject" -a file.log < file.log #WORKS
```

When using "strace" it works as well:

```
strace mutt myOwnMail@server.com -s "some_subject" -a file.log < file.log # WORKS
```

But when using "strace -f", it fails. Why?

```
strace -f mutt myOwnMail@server.com -s "some_subject" -a file.log < file.log # FAILS MISERABLY
```

The output:

```
[pid 24140] open("maildrop/816765.24140", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0644) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
[pid 24140] write(2, "postdrop: warning: mail_queue_en"..., 90postdrop: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/816765.24140: Permission denied
) = 90
[pid 24140] sendto(3, "<20>Aug 22 20:49:03 postfix/post"..., 124, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 124
[pid 24140] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [CHLD TSTP], 8) = 0
[pid 24140] nanosleep({10, 0}, 0x7ffd7e940140) = 0
[pid 24140] open("maildrop/817709.24140", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0644) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
[pid 24140] write(2, "postdrop: warning: mail_queue_en"..., 90postdrop: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/817709.24140: Permission denied
) = 90
[pid 24140] sendto(3, "<20>Aug 22 20:49:13 postfix/post"..., 124, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 124
[pid 24140] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [CHLD TSTP], 8) = 0
[pid 24140] nanosleep({10, 0}, 0x7ffd7e940140) = 0
[pid 24140] open("maildrop/818761.24140", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0644) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
[pid 24140] write(2, "postdrop: warning: mail_queue_en"..., 90postdrop: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/818761.24140: Permission denied
) = 90
[pid 24140] sendto(3, "<20>Aug 22 20:49:23 postfix/post"..., 124, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 124
[pid 24140] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [CHLD TSTP], 8) = 0
[pid 24140] nanosleep({10, 0}, ^Cstrace: Process 24137 detached
```

Why does the fork (-f option) ruin it?
Thanks!

EDIT:
When running the command:

```
sh -c 'find / -name \*postdrop\* -ls 2> /dev/null'
```

The output is:

```
2333274  216 -rwxr-sr-x   1 root     postdrop   218632 Oct 30  2018 /usr/sbin/postdrop
9426253    4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root         1629 Oct 30  2018 /usr/share/man/man1/postdrop.1.gz
```

Comment: Where do you see a failure? What is the difference in output? Also, what is the code causing the perceived error? Yes, that implies that you extract a [mcve] from mutt. Also note the descriptions of the tags you applied!

Comment: The underlying cause is covered by the older question [cannot strace sudo: reports that effective uid is nonzero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279612/cannot-strace-sudo-reports-that-effective-uid-is-nonzero)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `strace` log shows that the operation that's actually failing is an attempt to create a file named `maildrop/816765.24140` (in a directory somewhere in `/var/spool`, probably).  This, or a similar operation, fails when `mutt` is run under `strace -f` and succeeds when `mutt` is run under `strace` *without* the `-f` option.  We can deduce from these facts that it's not `mutt` itself that's failing, but some subprocess created by `mutt`.  Moreover, the failure code is `EACCES`, which means the problem is that *something* doesn't have the access privileges it needs *if and only if* it's being debugged (`strace` uses the debugger API to trace execution).

OK, so when does running a process with a debugger attached, cause it to lose access privileges that it otherwise would have?  When the process is executing a [*setuid* or *setgid* program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid).  These are specially marked programs that, normally, run with the access privileges of the user and/or group identity of the owner of the executable file.  That gives them the ability to do things that the invoking user can't normally do.  The canonical example of such a program is the `su` utility, which lets you run a shell as some other user if you know that user's password.

When a setuid or setgid program is run with a debugger attached, though, the kernel doesn't grant it its usual access privileges, because that would break security.  Imagine that you could run `su`, with all of its normal superpowers, under `gdb` -- that would let you bypass the password check and run a shell as *any* user whenever you want.

Going by the error messages, the program in question is named `postdrop`, so you can locate the executable and determine if it has one of these special marks with this command:

```bash
sh -c 'find / -name \*postdrop\* -ls 2> /dev/null'
```

**EDIT:** (Part of) the reported output of this command on your system is

```
2333274  216 -rwxr-sr-x   1 root     postdrop   218632 Oct 30  2018 /usr/sbin/postdrop
```

The numbers and the date aren't important for this question, so let's just look at the four key columns:

```
   -rwxr-sr-x  root  postdrop  /usr/sbin/postdrop
```

First, `/usr/sbin/postdrop` is a plausible full pathname for a program named `postdrop` that's invoked internally by `mutt`, so we know we're looking at the right thing.  (The *other* line of reported output from the `find` command refers to a file `/usr/share/man/man1/postdrop.1.gz`.  Everything in `/usr/share/man` is (supposed to be) documentation, not programs, so we can ignore that line.)

Second, `-rwxr-sr-x` gives the access control "mode" of the program -- who is allowed to read, write, and/or execute it.  The lowercase "s" is key.  In that position, it means that this program is *setgid*: it will run with the access control group identity of the group that owns the file, *not* the group identity of the user who ran the program.  This is exactly what I speculated was the case.  (An ordinary program would have the access control mode `-rwxr-xr-x`, and a *setuid* program like `sudo` would have mode `-rwsr-xr-x`.)

Third, "root postdrop" tells us the user and group who own the file, in that order.  This program executes with access control group identity "postdrop".  This is the same name as the program itself, which probably means this group is dedicated to the purpose of giving this program the privileges it needs to do its job (i.e. queue email for transmission).

So, conclusion: You can't use `strace -f` to observe the entire process of queuing email for transmission because that would involve running a setgid program under the debugger, contrary to system security policy.

This particular aspect of the Unix security policy is hardcoded into the kernel, and makes a lot more sense in the context of 1970s timesharing systems.  If you could run arbitrary code with the `postdrop` group's access privileges (which the debugger API would let you do, if debugging a setgid program didn't cancel the setgid effect) then you could probably read email that was in the process of being sent by other users on the same system.  Nobody wants that.

If you're on a personal workstation, one that only you can use *anyway*, then you should be able to bypass this rule by running `strace -f mutt` as root instead of your normal user account.  Root can *already* read everyone's mail, so the policy is not enforced for them.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation :).    Couldn't find what is wrong with the command...                 

find / -name '*postdrop*' -ls 2>/dev/null
find: paths must precede expression: 2
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

Comment: ... What shell are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using tcsh

Comment: Ah. Sorry, `2>` is a Bourne shell feature.  There is, unfortunately, no way to get the same effect in C shells.  I will edit the answer with a workaround.  In the long run I strongly recommend you switch to one of bash, zsh, or fish.

Comment: Here is the output:                                                                                                  
2333274  216 -rwxr-sr-x   1 root     postdrop   218632 Oct 30  2018 /usr/sbin/postdrop                                                                                                              
9426253    4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root         1629 Oct 30  2018 /usr/share/man/man1/postdrop.1.gz

Comment: Yep, it's the setgid bit that's responsible. Answer edited.

Comment: This is a pretty thorough analysis. I'm sure I've previously answered a "why doesn't ptrace work when setuid or setgid is set?" elsewhere on the site, but the quality of work here argues for the question to stay open despite being arguably duplicative.